# jaxws external binding file not used at runtime

Tags: java, applet, jax-ws

I have created a jaxws client applet that needs a binding file in order to avoid duplicate class names in the wsdl.  When wsimport is run using the binding file, the generated client classes are placed in different packages.  The client then works great when debugging through eclipse.

However, when the applet is run from a web page served through tomcat, the client fails due to IllegalAnnotationsException that two classes have the same XML type name.  Why is the client failing when executing from a jar, but not from eclipse?  Is my only option to modify the wsdl and access a locally stored version of the wsdl at runtime?

I am using jdk1.6.0_20 and the generated client target is jaxws 2.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be documented in this post [Ant 1.7.1 and package-info.java](http://www.javalinux.it/wordpress/2009/03/16/ant-171-and-package-infojava-compilation-problem-of-jax-ws-generated-classes/).  I was using ant to build the jar file, and the package-info.class file was not being created by the javac ant task.  Once package-info.class was included in the jar, then everything worked in the applet as it did while debugging through eclipse.